# How to implement blurred effect in the top navigation bar of Shiny-app

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny, shinyapps

I was trying to implement the `blurred` effect on the top navigation bar in my `Shiny-app` as explained in https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/RNMbGG.

Below is my `shiny-app` -

```
library(shiny)
ui =
shinyUI(fluidPage(
      tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML("
          #App_Body {
              height: auto;
              min-height: 10px;
              width: 100%;
              margin: 0 auto;
              padding: 0;
              background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.0);
              font-family: 'Calibri';
              position: relative;
            }

            #blurryscroll { 
              top: 0; left: 0; 
              width: 100%;
              height: 100px;
              overflow: hidden;
              position: fixed;
              filter: blur(4px); 
            }
            #App_Body1 {
              @extend #blurryscroll;
              filter: none; 

              height: 70px;
              width: 100%;
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
              background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.0);
              position: fixed;
              top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
              display: flex; flex-direction: row; text-align: left; align-items: center; justify-content: left;
              border-bottom: 0px solid #6a6a6a;
              z-index: 4;
            }

        "))
      ),
    tags$head(HTML("<script>
                        var pageContent = document.getElementById(\"navbarPage11\"),
                        pagecopy = pageContent.cloneNode(true),
                        blurryContent = document.getElementById(\"blurryscroll\");
                        blurryContent.appendChild(pagecopy);
                        window.onscroll = function() { blurryContent.scrollTop = window.pageYOffset; }
                    </script>
            ")),

    div(id = "App_Body",
        div(id = "blurryscroll", `aria-hidden` = TRUE),
        div(id = "App_Body1",
            HTML("What is Lorem Ipsum?
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.")
        )
    ),

    navbarPage(id = "navbarPage1", "Analysis navbarPage1", 
                        tabPanel(tabName = "Page1", 
                                    "Page1",
                                    div(id = "navbarPage11", style = "height: 2000px; width: 20%; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);",
                                        HTML("What is Lorem Ipsum?
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.")
                                    ) 
                                )
                )
))

server = function(input, output, session){}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As can be seen there, my `App` failed to bring the blurred effect despite implementing similar approach explained in the link.

Can you please help me to understand what exactly went wrong with my approach?

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Edited based on reply from Stéphane Laurent -

Modified app -

```
ui =
shinyUI(fluidPage(
      tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML("
          #App_Body {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
  font-family: 'Calibri';
  position: relative;
}

#blurryscroll, #App_Body1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed; 
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  filter: blur(4px);
}
#App_Body1 {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: left;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #6a6a6a;
  z-index: 4;
}

        "))
      ),
    tags$head(HTML("<script>
                        $(document).ready(function(){
  var pageContent = document.getElementById(\"navbarPage1\"),
      pagecopy = pageContent.cloneNode(true),
      blurryContent = document.getElementById(\"blurryscroll\");
  blurryContent.appendChild(pagecopy);
  window.onscroll = function() { blurryContent.scrollTop = window.pageYOffset; };
});
                    </script>
            ")),

    div(id = "App_Body",
        div(id = "blurryscroll", `aria-hidden` = TRUE),
        div(id = "App_Body1",
            HTML("What is Lorem Ipsum?
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.")
                )
    ),
    div(id="content",
        navbarPage(id = "navbarPage1", "Analysis navbarPage1", 
                            tabPanel(tabName = "Page1", 
                                        "Page1",
                                        div(id = "navbarPage11", style = "height: 2000px; width: 20%; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3)",
                                            HTML("What is Lorem Ipsum?
                                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
                                                )
                                        ) 
                                    )
                    ))
))

server = function(input, output, session){}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But with this elements of `App_Body1` getting blurred, however my goal was to blur elements of content of `navbarPage1`.

Comment: Hey @Bogaso - There's an error in the example. I'm getting an error in `tabPanel`: `Error in buildTabset(...): Tabs should all be unnamed arguments, but some are named: style`.

Comment: Corrected. It is fine now. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

1) You copied the SCSS code, instead of the CSS code (`@extend` is not CSS). Here is the CSS:

```css
#App_Body {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
  font-family: 'Calibri';
  position: relative;
}

#blurryscroll, #App_Body1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed; 
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  filter: blur(4px);
}
#App_Body1 {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .0);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: left;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #6a6a6a;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

2) You typed `navbarPage11` instead of `navbarPage1` in the JS code.

3) You have to encapsulate the JS code in a `$(document).ready(function(){...});`. Here is the JS code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var pageContent = document.getElementById(\"navbarPage1\"),
      pagecopy = pageContent.cloneNode(true),
      blurryContent = document.getElementById(\"blurryscroll\");
  blurryContent.appendChild(pagecopy);
  window.onscroll = function() { blurryContent.scrollTop = window.pageYOffset; };
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately still I failed to get desired effect. I wanted to blur elements of content of navbarPage1, but now contents of App_Body1 are getting blurred

Comment: @Bogaso What is the role of the `AppBody` div?

Comment: It is just a container of my original app to bring some special styling